# Prevent navigation property loading in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

As below, `AccountId` is both PK and FK. Maybe it's the reason why whenever I retrieve a `CandidateProfile` from the database, the property `Candidate` is automatically also loaded.

```
public class CandidateProfile
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Candidate))]
    public string AccountId { get; set; }
    public bool? IsIdle { get; set; }
    public string? About { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(80)]
    public string CareerTitle { get; set; }
    public WorkTypeEnum? WorkType { get; set; }
    public int? ExpectedSalary { get; set; }
    public EducationEnum? Education { get; set; }
    public LevelEnum? Level { get; set; }
    public int? YearOfExperience { get; set; }
    public string? Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }

    [ValidateNever]
    public Account? Candidate { get; set; }
    [ValidateNever]
    public List<JobField>? JobFields { get; set; }
    [ValidateNever]
    public List<Language>? Languages { get; set; }
}
```

How can I prevent loading of the `Candidate` property?

Comment: Try the [NotMapped] attribute.

Comment: Navigation property loads when 1) You use `Include` 2) You have defined `AutoInclude` 3) Navigation object already in `ChangeTracker` and EF just corrected refernce - use `AsNotracking` in this case,

Comment: You can't prevent EF Core loading the inverse navigation property when loading some navigation property. This is by design. EF Core has no problem with that, it is the correct behavior. Most likely you have problem with some sort of a serialization (Json?), in which case you must solve the problem there (and not EF Core). The other option is to use special classes just for serialization, which can be populated with `Select` and contain exactly the properties you need.